# Fail to build docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have code config Dockerfile below:

```docker
# Builder Stage
FROM rust:1.76.0 as builder
ENV SQLX_OFFLINE=true

# Create a new Rust project
RUN USER=root cargo new --bin jwt
WORKDIR /jwt/

# Copy and build dependencies
COPY Cargo.toml Cargo.lock ./entity/Cargo.toml  ./
RUN cargo build --release --locked
RUN rm src/*.rs

# Copy the source code and build the application
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release --locked

# Production Stage
FROM debian:buster-slim
ARG APP=/usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y ca-certificates tzdata \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV TZ=Etc/UTC \
    APP_USER=appuser

RUN groupadd $APP_USER \
    && useradd -g $APP_USER $APP_USER \
    && mkdir -p ${APP}

COPY --from=builder /jwt/ ${APP}/jwt

RUN chown -R $APP_USER:$APP_USER ${APP}

USER $APP_USER
WORKDIR ${APP}


ENTRYPOINT ["./jwt"]  
EXPOSE 8000
```

docker-compose.yml here:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  api-rust:
    image: username/api-rust
    container_name: api-rust
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
      JWT_SECRET_KEY: ${TOKEN}
      JWT_MAXAGE: ${JWT_MAXAGE}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - rust_app_network
      
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-h", "postgres", "-U", "${POSTGRES_USER}"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - rust_app_network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: ${PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT}
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - rust_app_network

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin-data:

networks:
  rust_app_network:
```

When i run "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d"

Have issues:

> Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./jwt": stat ./jwt: no such file or directory: unknown

Comment: Looks like `./jwt` is a directory. You cannot execute a directory as the `ENTRYPOINT`

Answer (score 1):

What is the binary file you want to run?

```
COPY --from=builder /jwt/ ${APP}/jwt
```

Because you copied like this, you have to know which file you want to execute.
e.g. `/jwt/somefile`  is the file you want to execute

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./jwt"]
```

->

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./jwt/somefile"]
```